# selenium bot proxy support

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I added proxy support to the bot I coded using Python and selenium, but when the browser is opened to proxies with `ip:port:username:password`, the proxy does not automatically login using the proxy's username password. please help.

```py
self.proxy_option = int(input(Style.BRIGHT+Fore.GREEN+'['+Fore.GREEN+'>'+Fore.GREEN+'] ['+Fore.GREEN+'1'+Fore.GREEN+']Proxy [1] Proxyless [0]: '))
self.browser_amount = int(input(Style.BRIGHT+Fore.RED+'['+Fore.RED+'>'+Fore.RED+'] Threads: '))
self.profile = (input(Style.BRIGHT+Fore.GREEN+'['+Fore.GREEN+'>'+Fore.GREEN+'] Song: '))
self.wait_before_start = float(input(Style.BRIGHT+Fore.GREEN+'['+Fore.GREEN+'>'+Fore.GREEN+'] Value (10): '))
print('')

def GetRandomProxy(self):
    proxies = self.ReadFile('proxy.txt', 'r')
    proxy = choice(proxies)
    proxy_parts = proxy.split(':')
    if len(proxy_parts) >= 4:
        proxy_ip, proxy_port, proxy_username, proxy_password = proxy_parts[:4]
        return (proxy_ip, proxy_port, proxy_username, proxy_password)
    else:
        proxy_ip, proxy_port = proxy_parts[:2]
        return (proxy_ip, proxy_port, None, None)  

def Login(self, username, password, driver, proxy_username=None, proxy_password=None):
    if self.proxy_option == 1:
        proxy_ip, proxy_port, _, _ = self.GetRandomProxy()
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}')
        if proxy_username and proxy_password:
            chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-auth={proxy_username}:{proxy_password}')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

I have added selenium support to my python bot without any problems, but the username password information in the `ip:port:username:password` proxies does not automatically transfer to the browser. It asks me to enter manually.